# Java/JavaFX, read files from inside project and jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, file, javafx

I have some images and xml files inside my project folders which I want to read. For example, my code is inside `src/app/MyClass.java`. The files I want to read are in `res/filename.png`, `res/filename.xml`.

So if I wanted to give my project an icon, I would do this (works fine if running through Eclipse):

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:res/icon.png"));
```

The problem with this is that when I run it through the .jar file, the image does not appear. Same thing with other files. It can't find the xml file through the jar file.

I tried this:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/icon.png");
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(input));
```

But Eclipse says that `input` is `null`. What am I doing wrong? Any help would appreciated!

Comment: Check whether the Jar contains your image inside.

Comment: Yes, the images and xml files are inside the jar file. I opened it with 7-zip to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities as to why this is the case. The first of which is you are running a JAR and not an Executable Jar File. Another possible reason why the program fails to display images is that when exporting you are not clicking the extract required libraries button as shown below. If neither of these are the case comment below.

[image: Once you click finish you should be able to run the file with no issue.]

---

Try creating a `source folder` named `resources` (right click project > New > Source Folder) and put everything in there. You can now do `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.ext")` and it shouldn't be `null`.

If there are any other errors after you create your jar file (following the picture above), you can run this through command line/terminal and it should show you any errors you may have:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar
```

Comment: I was following this tutorial to make a jar file: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1. When I try it using your way, nothing comes up when I double click the jar file. It appears to be opened in the background (task manager shows a Java process running). This also happens sometimes when I follow the linked tutorial, but rarely. Not sure what is wrong with my project structure.

Comment: Erm well this is the tutorial I used to export stuff. It is for EXE but in the process you create a Runnable JAR File. http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse

Comment: I figured it out. Added the solution as an edit to your post. Creating the jar file with your tutorial was way better. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem glad it helped.